# maxpooling what should the indices be when there're multiple max values?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, backpropagation, max-pooling

What to do when there are multiple values in the kernel that equals to the max? For example, for these values:

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

The max is simply 0. What should max indices look like? should it be True's for **all** occurrence of max:

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Or the **first** occurrence of the max:

```
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]])
```

Pytorch uses the first occurrence of the max, while some [source](https://numbersmithy.com/2d-and-3d-pooling-using-numpy/#Vectorized_version) uses the other one (he uses `pos = np.where(result == view, 1, 0)`, which essentially records 1 for all occurrence of max).

**Edit**: for forward prop it doesn't matter, but during backpropagation, for example, if the upstream gradient is `[[1,1],[1,1]]`, then the gradient of current node will be different: `[[1,1],[1,1]]` (all occurrence) vs `[[1,0],[0,0]]` (first occurrence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After even a single back-propagation it is very unlikely that the kernel values will remain equal. So it shouldn't be a real issue, should it?

Comment: Yep it make sense. It's just I'm comparing my result with pytorch and they are not matched. Took me a long time to find this issue :)

Comment: So in the end this is a design decision.